# jquery draggable with added keypress functionality

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard-shortcuts, draggable

I want to implement the "draggable" control from jQueryUI.
When the user drags an icon with the mouse, he can then drop that icon somewhere(e.g. on an image).

I also want to have advanced functionality - when the user presses a key, an icon is attached to the mouse and with a mouse click, the icon can be dropped(at the same places as an icon that is dragged).

A similar functionality has been implemented in the Silverlight game Robozzle: http://robozzle.com/

Obviously, I'll use this: http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/, but my question is:
How do I programmatically create and attach a jQuery draggable object to the mouse cursor?
I.e. without actually dragging it with the mouse.

Comment: Did you try my solution or is this not what you're looking for? Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Your solution works, but "reimplement draggable" isn't what I'm looking for. I use advanced "droppable" functionality that still needs to work. I will post what I ended up using - later today.

Answer (score 1):

To have most of this functionality, you don't even need jQuery UI or any plugins. Have a look at my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cJzeP/2/

If you want to keep dragging on the icons instead of my clicking solution, you can easily combine the two. See the comments in the code for more explanations if needed.

HTML:

```
<div id="iconA" class="icon">A</div>
<div id="iconB" class="icon">B</div>
<div id="iconC" class="icon">C</div>

<div class="drop">Drop stuff here: </div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon { display:inline-block; margin:5px; background-color:whitesmoke; border:1px solid silver; width:20px; height:20px; text-align:center; }

.drop { padding:20px; border:1px solid blue; }
```

Javascript:

```
// The dragged element wrapped in a jQuery object or null
var $dragHelper = null;

// The last known mouse position The keypress event doesn't
// send the position through, we need this for the hotkey
// activation so we can show the icon next to the cursor.
var lastX = 0;
var lastY = 0;

// Start dragging the element with the passed id
function StartDrag(id){
    // Clone the element, make it absolutely positioned and
    // append it to the body.
    $dragHelper = $('#' + id).clone().css('position', 'absolute').appendTo('body');

    // Fire the dragging event to update the helper's position
    Dragging();

    // If the user clicks anything outside the drop area,
    // stop dragging.
    $(document).click(StopDrag);
}

function StopDrag(){
    // Remove the helper from the DOM and clear the variable.
    $dragHelper.remove();
    $dragHelper = null;

    // Unbind the document click event which is now useless.
    $(document).unbind('click', StopDrag);
}

// Fires on mousemove and updates element position
function Dragging(e){
    // Only update last known mouse position if an event object
    // was passed through (mousemove event).
    if(e){
        lastX = e.pageX;
        lastY = e.pageY;
    }

    // If an element is being dragged, update the helper's position.
    if($dragHelper)
        $dragHelper.css({ top: lastY, left: lastX });
}

// What happens when a key is pressed?
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    var ch = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
    switch(ch){
        case 'a':
            StartDrag('iconA');
            break;
        case 'b':
            StartDrag('iconB');
            break;
        case 'c':
            StartDrag('iconC');
            break;
    }
});

// Bind the document mousemove event as we need to update our last
// known mouse coordinates constantly for the keypress event.
$(document).mousemove(Dragging);

// Make the icons clickable
$('.icon').click(function(e){
    // Start dragging this icon if it's clicked
    StartDrag($(this).attr('id'));

    // We need to stop event bubbling as it would straight away
    // trigger a click on the document, which stops dragging.
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// Make our drop area clickable
$('.drop').click(function(){
    // Only do something is an element is being dragged
    if($dragHelper){
        // Stuff to do when an element is dropped goes here.

        // For the sake of this example, we just clone the helper
        // and append it to our drop container.
        $dragHelper.clone().css({
            position: 'relative',
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px'
        }).appendTo(this);

        // Stop dragging if an element was successfully dropped.
        StopDrag();
    }
});
```